# Computer forces me in the BIOS settings when I turn it on

Tags: windows

My computer forces me into the BIOS settings when I turn it on.
Before that happening it said on a black screen “checking media presence”

Comment: This typically happens when the boot disk is dead.

Comment: Get the manufacturer's (including disk manufacturer) diagnostic App and test the drive for errors

Comment: Could also be that the motherboard CMOS battery is dying.